# Regular Expressions in Ruby issue

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string like this `/4/LM2301_800.mp4`.

I would like to use a regex to strip the `/4/` and the `_800` from the file name.

I am currently trying to use the strip command. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what value you want from `4/LM2301_800.mp4`?

Comment: yes. i want.  LM2301.mp4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
" /4/LM2301_800.mp4".scan(/.*\/(.*?)_\d*(.*)/).join
 => "LM2301.mp4"
```

Comment: If you need me to explain it better, let me know.

Answer (score 3):

Your file could be deeply nested inside a directory structure:

```
 path =  "/4/LM2301_800.mp4"
 path.sub(/^(\/.)*\/(.*)_\d+\.mp4/, $2)
 => "LM2301"    # you already know these are mp4 files, so you could add the suffix
```

Or:

```
 path =  "/4/LM2301_800.mp4" 
 path.sub(/^(\/.)*\/(.*)_\d+\.(.*)/, $2+'.'+$3)
 => "LM2301.mp4"
```